# How to style this div using material ui card/box

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui, jsx

Currently, I'm using a flexed div to contain the h1 and the Image of the arrow (as seen [image: here]). Is there a way to use a material UI component to restyle this "black box"?

the part of jsx code for this "black box":

```
<div className={homeStyles.flex}>
      <span>
        <h1 className={homeStyles.landingText}>LISTEN TO ORCAS LIVE!</h1>{' '}
      </span>
      <span className={homeStyles.landingArrow}>
        <Image src={arrow} width="30px" height="30px" />
      </span>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.flex {
  z-index: 2;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background-color: #000000;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 20px;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin:0px auto 0 auto;
  transform: translateY(-500%);
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: center;
  width: 40vw;
  height:5rem

}

.landingText {
  font-family: 'Mukta', sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 44px;
  line-height: 100%;
  color: white;
  padding: 27px 10px 29px 33px;
  position: relative;
  
}

.landingArrow {
  position: relative;
  top: 35%;
  right: 2px;
  width: 30px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  padding-right: 4px;
}
```

I want to change it because the current setup doesn't work for all screen sizes. For example, text and the arrow image aren't aligned at the end and middle of the box for smaller screens: [image]

Comment: Is there a specific need for you to switch to MaterialUI components? You didn't clearly indicate the problem here. I think it looks decent as it is right now.

Comment: @GaëtanBoyals I clarified the reason I want to change it. MUI also provides a smoother transition between screen sizes. I'm happy to provide more info if that helps you help me:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm only going to post a minimal example since you seem knowledgeable enough to tweak it to fit your needs! It should be *fairly* responsive, but I'll let you test it fully.

It uses [Cards](https://mui.com/components/cards/) and [Typography](https://mui.com/components/typography/)

```
return (
    <Card style={{backgroundColor: '#0f0059', borderRadius:'10px'}}>
      <Typography variant="h3" style={{color: "#ffffff"}}>
        LISTEN TO ORCAS LIVE! &rarr;
      </Typography>
    </Card>
  );
```

Note that I used `style={{}}`, but Material recommends using `sx` in their [documentation](https://mui.com/customization/how-to-customize/).

I stay available in the comments if this doesn't answer your question.